# Rendering a partial via coffeescript prints literal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to render a partial from coffeescript when a button is clicked, so I have one of my coffeescript files "script.js.coffee" with the following code:

```
$('[id^="btn_add_rep_dia_"]').click ->
    id = this.id.substring(16)
    $("#dia" + id).append("<%= j render('repeticions/form') %>")
```

But what's happenning is that at the end of `$("#dia" + id)` appears litterally the text `"<%= j render('repeticions/form') %>"`. The partial is located in "repeticions" folder and it's called "_form.html.haml"

I have also tested the last code line as:

```
$("#dia" + id).append("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'repeticions/form') %>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute an `erb` (embedded ruby) template inside a `.coffee` file. Rails doesn't know that it should pre-process the file before sending it to the client.

If you are using a Rails version > 3.2, then simply renaming your coffeescript file from `script.js.coffee` to `script.js.coffee.erb` should be enough to instruct rails to interpret the erb style template strings (`<%...%>`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't render a partial from a plain coffeescript file.  If you wanted to do this approach, I suggest turning that button into a link_to with remote: true which will enable you to use ajax in rails.